How to diagnose a Master/ Slave clutch problem, vs a worn clutch itself?
There's got to be a better way than just "throwing parts at it" , until one of them solves it.
In diagnosing an inability to put the car into gear, what might help differentiate a problem originating from a failing master cylinder vs one due to a failing slave cylinder?
(Assuming there's nothing obvious, like visible leaks, fluid around the components, obviously busted seals, etc.)
One guy on YouTube casually mentioned that pumping the clutch can usually restore some pressure in the master cylinder temporarily, and that when doing so, works, this can be a good indication the problem is with the master cylinder, rather than the slave. Is this true?
And how to differentiate these two from a problem that originates from a worn clutch itself?
Aside from an amateurish, parts- changing process of elimination, how can you tell what the source of the issue is?

Typically, a clutch is going to fail in one of two ways.
First, it loses friction material which ultimately will allow it to slip. This happens over time and/or hard use. One of the ways to check for slippage is while the vehicle is rolling at slower speeds (suggested 25-30 MPH), put it in a much higher gear than you'd normally be in, release the clutch pedal all the way, then progressively press on the go pedal. If the engine speeds up faster than the vehicle does, it is more or less slipping.
Secondly, the flywheel can get heat cracks caused by overheating. This can be caused from riding the clutch pedal or slipping the clutch too much. What is "too much" ... who really knows, but more than you should be. When there is an excessive amount of heat built up in the clutch and flywheel, it can cause the heat cracks. This exhibits itself by causing jidders in how the clutch operates. When you're releasing the clutch pedal you'd be feeling rhythmic grabbing. It's very annoying and very noticeable.
If the slave is failing, the first way it can fail is by leaking. This should be noticeable under the vehicle. If the slave is located inside of the bell housing, you might see it leaking down at the bottom where the bell housing meets the engine. There may be an inspection cover there or whatever. Many have either a small hole there or some other way for liquid to escape. Please note, on many vehicles a rear main seal would leak to the same location, so you'd need to check what type of fluid you're finding there. If there is hydraulic fluid from the slave leaking into the bell housing, it will most likely contaminate the friction disk and cause the clutch to fail.
If the master if failing via leakage, you'd most likely notice it inside of the car. The end which would leak usually sticks through the firewall near where the rod attaches to the clutch pedal.
The master/slave can also leak past the piston which causes what you describe in your question. Sometimes pumping the clutch pedal can gain you some extra leverage and make it easier to disengage the clutch. The only way I'm aware of determining if a clutch is leaking internally besides pumping the clutch pedal is if the transmission is otherwise hard to put into gear when the vehicle is sitting still, engine running. The problem here is, if the 1st to 2nd synchronizer is going bad, it can exhibit the same type of issues. I mention 1st to 2nd synchro mainly because of all the synchros, it is usually the first to go because it takes the most abuse of any of the synchros. If you are feeling resistance in any gear (sitting still, engine running, clutch pedal pressed), it is most likely something going on with the master/slave and not synchros. Is this foolproof? Not by any means. It does give you a good indication one way or the other, though.
